# How to Retrieve Multiple Check Boxes added to single Column?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have 7 checkboxes the checkbox text is Days name e.g Mon, Tue, Wed.....
I Want to **retrieve** data to my **Checkboxes** which are added to a **single** **column**

> Add button code

```
private void button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String s = "";
            foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            {

                if (c is CheckBox)
                {

                    CheckBox b = (CheckBox)c;
                    if (b.Checked)
                    {

                        s = b.Text + "," + s;

                    }
                    s = s.TrimEnd(',');
                }
            }

            cmd = new SqlCommand("update AddWork set NWorkDay=@name,Days=@Wday,TimePday=@Hours where ID=@id", con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", noWork.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Wday", s);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hours", Hours.Text);


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");

            con.Close();
            ShowData();
            ClearData();
        }
```

Adding to my database is not the problem it is working when I click a column in a view I can get the hours and no of work values in the form but I cant get the check boxes values ticked I need a solution to get them in check boxes

> data grid view code

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

           //dataTable is my data grid view name

            ID = Convert.ToInt32(dataTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            noWork.Text = dataTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            
            Hours.Text = dataTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: I don't know the answer but I have a suggestion. Use `StringBuilder` for appending operations.

Comment: I do not get what you are asking. You should give an example of what you are trying to do. You state that… _”I Want to retrieve data to my Checkboxes which are added to a single column”_ … ? Where in the code are you attempting to “get” these “check box” values from the grid? In addition, the grids `CellContentClick` event is confusing. The “grid” appears to be named `dataGridView1`, however, the comment states, and the code uses (I am guessing) a grid that is (strangely) named `dataTable.`

Comment: Granted you “can” do this, however, this is confusing when trying to understand what is going on in the code. In other words, the `CellContentClick` event appears to be fired from one grid (`dataGridView1`) and the code appears to reference another grid (`dataTable`)? Assuming the grid IS named `dataTable` then “where” in the `CellContentClick` event is the code attempting to get a cell’s “check box” value? I do not see any code in the event that tries to get a check boxes value. Can you clarify any of this?

Comment: @JohnG >dataTable is my **dataGridView1**; I need to get those check box values in the database added to a column when I Click a row in the Datagridview

Comment: @JohnG if I click that datagridview i need checkboxes checked according to data entered in the column

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something, but I still do not understand what “check boxes” you are referring to. It looks like there are seven check boxes on the form, however, it is unknown if there are check boxes in the grid. I suggest you describe what you are wanting to do with an example.

Comment: You state… _”if I click that datagridview i need checkboxes checked according to data entered in the column”_ … ? So… The code needs to “check” a particular check box on the form if a cell in the selected row in a grid contains certain values? Again, an example would probably be an easier way to describe what you want to achieve. What values in the grid would you be comparing to determine which check box should be “checked”? I am obviously missing something.

Comment: Also, if you do add additional information, DO NOT ADD this new info as a comment. Add it to the original question. You should [edit] your question to add the additional info.